# Button inside every product

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am doing a little school project with ASP.NET, and I'm trying to get all products from the Database, show it and have "Add to card" button for every one of them. I managed to do all this, except adding the button. I have a function that gets all the products and I'm binding it with ASP Repeater. The problem is, when I try to add a button, it says that I need to use the form tag first, when I add the form tag it says it needs to have runat="server", but when I add it, it says I can't have more than one runat="server". The Repeater tag is using it also, and I'm stuck. Can anyone suggest something? Thank you!

```
private void bindPopularProducts()
{
    String CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Food", con))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                DataTable fFood = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(fFood);
                popularFood.DataSource = fFood;
                popularFood.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this

```
<asp:Repeater ID="popularFood" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div><%# Eval("name") %></div>
                    <div><asp:Image ID="foodImage" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "~/images/food/" + Eval("image").ToString() %>' Visible="true" CssClass="img-responsive" /></div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 text-left"><%# "$"+Eval("price_small")+"/small" %></div>



                        <div class="col-md-8 text-right">


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

I'm trying to put the button inside the text-right div

Comment: Maybe show your code :)

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

Within your Repeater's `ItemTemplate`, add a button. In the button, set the `CommandArgument` to some key value that uniquely identifies the product.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Click Me" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Product.Key") %>' OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

In your code, the event handler can use the button's `CommandArgument` to get the product key and execute your "Add to card" method.

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string myProductKey;

        // Use "myProductKey" to do something with the Product record...
        myProductKey = ((Button)sender).CommandArgument;
    }
```

Comment: I get this error when I add it. "Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation."